# Move a child element positioned absolutely outside of its parent container

Tags: css

I'm trying to move the green box 10px outside of the top of its container. However, since `.cover` has an overflow of hidden, the top of the green box isn't showing. How can I show the green box without switching around elements in the DOM?

Sorry for the confusion and the lack of info. Also, if I take off `overflow: hidden` or switch it to `visible`, the container reduces to `0` height which then hides a vertical border (on the site I'm working on) that spans the height of the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxbf45y0/1/

Comment: You take off `overflow:hidden`?  Is this a trick question?

Comment: You can't. Overflow hidden is doing what it does: hiding anything that falls beyond its boundaries. You will either have to use `overflow: visible` or move the child up one level. I don't see why you need to use overflow hidden anyway, unless you want to clear floated children. If that's the case you'll have to use the `::after` pseudoelement to clear floats instead of using the `overflow: hidden` trick.

Comment: @Joseph Sorry about that. I added more info.

Comment: than you clearly have floating issues. Add a *"clearFix"* class to your element (instead of `overflow`) and you're done: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I take off overflow: hidden or switch it to visible, the container reduces to 0 height which then hides a vertical border

Sounds like you're using `overflow:hidden;` to create a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).  Obviously the side effect is that you can't easily have any overflow.  That MDN page I linked includes a list of ways to force a new block formatting context.  One thing you can do is replace `overflow:hidden;` with `display:inline-block; width:100%;`.  This demo uses that method: https://jsfiddle.net/sb40ha0n/

As pointed out by Roko C. Buljan, Clearfix methods might also be available to correct this issue.

Comment: Thanks, replacing `overflow: hidden` with `display: inline-block` did the trick. However, when I add `width: 100%`, it actually reduces the width of the div. Without adding that, the site looks fine. Thanks, I'll check you off in a minute.